# how set F12 as Prefix for GNU screen?

Tags: gnu-screen

```
escape F12 # does not work
```

Other Trys:

```
escape ^|^| # ctrl+\ as prefix

escape ^@@ # ctrl+space

escape `e # ~ as prefix

escape ^[[24~ # F12 nope did not work :( F2 are F12
```

Screen version 4.00.03

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a function key, because that sends multiple characters.  According to the manual:

> **`escape`** *xy*
>
> Set the command character to *x* and the character generating  a  literal
>   command  character  (by triggering the "meta" command) to y (similar to
>   the -e option).  Each argument is either a  single  character,  a  two-character  sequence  of the form `"^x"` (meaning `"C-x"`), a backslash followed by an octal number (specifying the ASCII code of the  character),
>   or  a  backslash  followed by a second character, such as `"\^"` or `"\\"`.
>   The default is `"^Aa"`.

Each form, however expressed, corresponds to a single ASCII code.

Comment: it work in tmux hope it was a way in gnu screen too :)